# How can I turn off a Wireless Xbox One controller on Windows 10?

Tags: controllers, windows-10

How can I turn off my Xbox One controller using a Win10 PC without having to remove the batteries?

Comment: Do you have the wireless adapter or using the USB cable? I think the controller turns off after a few seconds after disconnecting the adapter.  And I could have sworn the controller turns off eventually if you disconnect the USB cable.

Comment: @JeffMercado Wireless adapter. Pulling the adapter is nearly as inconvenient as pulling the cable. I tried waiting for a few min for it to turn off, but not terribly long; I just got it yesterday.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Just hold Xbox guide button for 5+ seconds.

Comment: AKA the big Home Button that lights up

Comment: I have a wireless adapter and an XBox 360 controller.  On Windows 10, no matter how long I hold down the guide button, it doesn't turn the controller off.

Comment: @braveterry that's because this is for the Xbox One controller. 360's don't do that. For the 360 I just quickly pop the bat pack off and on.

Comment: Didn't work for me. No mather how long I hold it, wont turn the light off.

Comment: More like 8 seconds, but it does work for me.

Answer (score -5):

There's no other way to shut it down right now.

Comment: Except, there is.

Answer (score -5):

Unplug it from the computer, and hold the Xbox button down for more than 5 seconds.

Comment: Although you can not see it from the "first post" review queue, this answer has already been posted, by another user over a month ago. While it is correct, we frown on duplicate answers. If you wish to clarify that this works, simply upvote the accepted answer.